# Getting Different results with "LEFT OUTER JOIN" and "IN", where did my logic go wrong?

Tags: t-sql, join

I have four tables, one is a Master Invoice table and three others are Invoices from different region.  What I am trying to achieve is to return only records from the Master Invoice table where the invoice number is in one of the other three tables.  For example:

```
 SELECT * FROM Invoice_Master M
 LEFT OUTER JOIN Invoice_North N
   ON M.InvNo = N.InvNo
 LEFT OUTER JOIN Invoice_East E
   ON M.InvNo = E.InvNo
 LEFT OUTER Invoice_South S
   ON M.InvNo = S.InvNo
 WHERE N.InvNo IS NOT NULL
   OR E.InvNo IS NOT NULL
   OR S.InvNo IS NOT NULL
```

The logic is if I "LEFT OUTER JOIN" the 3 tables to the Master table, if any InvNo is not null then the invoice must exist in the original Master table.

However, when I write the code in this Implicit Join I get a slightly less records in return:

```
 select * FROM Invoice_Master
 WHERE InvNo IN (
   SELECT InvNo FROM Invoice_North)
 OR InvNo IN (
   SELECT InvNo FROM Invoice_East)
 OR InvNo IN (
   SELECT InvNo FROM Invoice_South)
```

Where did my logic go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference could be due to the fact that the second query selects discrete rows from the master table, whereas your first query could be returing join-results that have duplicate rows. i.e. if the left outer join matched two rows in, say, `invoice_north`, then both those rows will be shown in the main `select`.

Comment: Ah, this is brilliant, when I used "SELECT DISTINCT InvNo" I got the same record counts.  I had been scratching my head all day with this problem!  Thanks!